# Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I use this query:

```
SELECT DocumentosPorTercero.CodigoSucursal, 
       Sucursal.NombreSucursal, 
       DocumentosPorTercero.IdTercero, 
       Terceros.NombreTercero, 
       DocumentosPorTercero.Observaciones,    
       CASE 
         WHEN Terceros.PersonaNatural = '1' THEN 'Natural' 
         WHEN Terceros.PersonaNatural = '0' THEN 'Jurídico' 
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS TipoTercero, 
       ReporteDocumentos.FechaDiligenciamiento, 
       CASE 
         WHEN ReporteDocumentos.Cedula = '1' THEN 'v' 
         WHEN ReporteDocumentos.Cedula = '0' THEN '-'
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS Cedula, 
       CASE 
         WHEN ReporteDocumentos.ConstanciaDeIngresos = '1' THEN 'v' 
         WHEN ReporteDocumentos.ConstanciaDeIngresos = '0' THEN '-' 
         ELSE NULL
       END AS ConstanciaDeIngresos,
       CASE 
         WHEN ReporteDocumentos.Declaracion = '1' THEN 'v' 
         WHEN ReporteDocumentos.Declaracion = '0' THEN '-' 
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS Declaracion, 
       CASE 
         WHEN ReporteDocumentos.Camara = '1' THEN 'v' 
         WHEN ReporteDocumentos.Camara = '0' THEN '-'
         ELSE NULL
       END AS Camara,     
       DocumentosPorTercero.NumeroEnvio
  FROM DocumentosPorTercero 
  JOIN Sucursal ON DocumentosPorTercero.CodigoSucursal = Sucursal.CodigoSucursal 
  JOIN Terceros ON DocumentosPorTercero.IdTercero = Terceros.IdTercero 
  JOIN TipoDocumentos ON DocumentosPorTercero.IdTipoDocumento = TipoDocumentos.IdTipoDocumento  
  JOIN ReporteDocumentos ON DocumentosPorTercero.IdDocumento = ReporteDocumentos.IdDocumento
 WHERE DocumentosPorTercero.CodigoSucursal = 21
```

This throws the error:

> "Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

I don't understand why, I'm not using subqueries.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Are any of these things that you're joining on a VIEW instead of a TABLE?  Maybe there's an error in the VIEW?

Comment: Could also be happening if you are using a trigger.  Any triggers that could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using views, and one of those views is giving the error